# Passing HashMap to other activity throws class cast Exception

Tags: java, android, exception, casting

I want to pass a HashMap to other Activity my hash map is

```
HashMap<Integer,float[][]> table;
```

I use this code to send it to other activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, LineChartActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("map",table);
                startActivity(i);
```

when I receive it

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        table = (HashMap<Integer, float[][]>) intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
```

the **VERY weird thing** is that  this code works very well in Android 5 and higher but in the previous versions Eg 4.4.4 ,4.1.1 it throw

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to
>   float[][]

Does someone face this problem before ? please I need any solution

Comment: Yes pretty strange that it worked once because Java doesn't support primitive generics, only objects. You could try using a wrapper object instead.